# Error in including MongoDB C++ driver in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mongodb, ubuntu

I have been trying to connect C++ with MongoDB but it gave errors on many levels and now I'm stuck at compiling a simple code. I have followed this [tutorial](https://mongodb-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver.html). And I tried to compile the code given in the tutorial using the command below.

```
g++ tutorial.cpp -Iinstall/include -Linstall/lib -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial
```

But it prints a huge log on the console and exits with a error. The final part output is below.

```
 nce to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
install/lib/libmongoclient.a(dbclient.o): In function `perl_matcher':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:374: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
install/lib/libmongoclient.a(dbclient.o): In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_match()':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher_non_recursive.hpp:973: undefined reference to `boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone explain how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected this error by adding "lboost_regex" to the build path. I have corrected all the errors in official tutorial [here](http://bitsflip.blogspot.com/2015/05/connecting-mongodb-with-c.html) in this blog post.

Comment: Please note that the tutorial you have linked to in your blog post is long out of date. The correct tutorial for the legacy driver is here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Tutorial